# Getting "Job found still running after platform shutdown" error for silent mode execution

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am using following code (by creating new Thread) to write results to HTML.

```
private void asyncHTMLWriter(final IResults results) throws IOException {
    Thread htmlThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // write results to html
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ioException = e;
            }
        }
    }, "HTMLThread"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    htmlThread.start();
}
```

But when I implemented same using Job, seeing "Job found still running after platform shutdown" error.

```
private void asyncHTMLWriter1(final IResults results) throws IOException {
    Job job = new Job("HTMLJob") {

        @Override
        public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                if (family.equals("HTMLJob")) {
                    return true;
            }
            return super.belongsTo(family);
        }

        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            try {
                // write results to html
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();
}
```

I am seeing this error only for silent mode execution. 
Any thoughts why I am seeing this error when I use Job.

Comment: Are you exiting soon after the Job is scheduled? If so it may not have run yet which gives this message.

Comment: @greg-449  Yes, you are right, it looks like we are exiting soon after the Job is scheduled. But when I use Thread, then we are not seeing this error. Any ideas to fix this with Job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the jobs in a family have finished you can use:

```
Job.getJobManager().join(family, progress-monitor);
```

so call this before you exit.

Comment: I still don't understand why we wont see this error for Thread ?

Comment: The 'Job still running' message comes from the Job Manager and that only looks at Job threads. Other non-daemon threads might stop the shutdown from finishing until they exit but they won't generate this message.